# How can i add custom filter to kendo UI grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to add customer filters to my kendo grid.

I want search string in some case , in some case number and compare strings.

```
 <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="_jobsPostedDetails" [pageSize]="gridComfig.firstPageSize" [sortable]="gridComfig.sortable"
            [pageable]="{refresh: true,pageSizes: true,buttonCount: 5}" [filterable]="gridComfig.filterable" [height]="gridComfig.firstHeight">
            <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
                <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand><span class="k-icon k-i-file-excel"></span>Export to Excel</button>
            </ng-template>
            <!--<kendo-grid-column field="_idRestaurant" title="Restaurant Account" filter="numeric" width="150"></kendo-grid-column>-->
            <kendo-grid-column field="restaurantType" title="Restaurant Type" width="150" ></kendo-grid-column>

            <kendo-grid-column field="experience" title="Experience" width="150"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="postedDate" title="Job Created Date" width="250">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    {{dataItem.postedDate | date:ShortDate}}</ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>

        </kendo-grid>
```